# django: Count objects with the same value

Tags: django, django-queryset

Lets say I have following models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    author = models.FK(Author)


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
```

And I want to write something to get a list of authors with annotated field which shows amount of books in each language. Can't imagine an annotation for it :(, e.g. {'en': 10, 'ru': 1...etc}

e.g. just counts all, `Author.objects.annotate(languages=Count(book__lang))`

Comment: Have a look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/ for more information on Aggregation / Annotation

Comment: I think I was looking there. But did not find exact idea :(

Answer (score 4):

Simple annotation should help you:

```
Book.objects.values('lang').annotate(lang=Count('author')).order_by('lang')
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it without casting queryset to a list? E.g. if I still want to use it?

Comment: Well the suggestion @suhain gave didn't cast queryset to list, if you do `type(query_result)` on the return value you will see what it is.

Comment: yes, true. It makes value query set. Which is a bit different. E.g. I don't have initial qs, and also I have a way more items inside e.g. extra item per region)